# JQuery creating unwanted option tag in select menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am having an issue involving a `multiple` `select` menu. The user has the ability to `select` multiple items from Selectbox A and add them to Selectbox B. I Use `jQuery` to add the items to an array each time the add button is `clicked` and populate Selectbox B using a `foreach` `loop` in `php` and for the most part it is working fine.

However the issue is that when the user adds the first item to Selectbox A it adds the item but also an empty `option` tag which I do not want. Is there anything I can do to resolve this?

This is my `HTML` code:

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="active" name="activecontributors[]">
    <option value="0"> </option>
</select>
```

This is my `JQuery` code:

```
var drop2html = $("#active").html();        
    //ADD/REMOVE functionality for the contributors select boxes. 
    $('#addBtn').click(function (e) {//Adding
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#compresult option:selected').each(function(){
            drop2html += '<option value="' + $(this).val() + '">' + $(this).text() + '</option>';
        })
        $("#active").html(drop2html);
    });

    $('#removeBtn').click(function (e){//Removing
         e.preventDefault();
         $('#active option:selected').each(function(){
             $('#active option:selected').remove();
        })
        drop2html = $('#active').html();
    });

     //on submit select all the options in active contributors...
    $('#mainform').submit(function(){
        $("#active option").attr("selected", "selected");
     });
```

For some reason when the page loads it always shows the `option` tag. I would like for my select box to show no `option` tag if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its because of the empty option already present in that menu.

```
$('#compresult option:selected').each(function(){
        drop2html = '<option value="' + $(this).val() + '">' + $(this).text() + '</option>';
})
```

try this for without appending to the string or

```
var drop2html = '';
```

store empty value to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code without `drop2html` variable and get rid of your problem :

```
$(function(){
    //remove empty option from active
    $('#active option').remove();

    $('#addBtn').click(function (e) {//Adding
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#compresult option:selected').each(function(){
                $('#active').append('<option value="' + $(this).val() + '">' + $(this).text() + '</option>');
            })
        });

        $('#removeBtn').click(function (e){//Removing
             e.preventDefault();
             $('#active option:selected').each(function(){
                 $('#active option:selected').remove();
            })
        });
});
```

Comment: I've implemented your suggestion but I am still getting an issue even without `drop2html`. Everytime I load the page the `#active` selectbox displays an empty select option I don't want.

Comment: see my updated answer. I have added `$('#active option').remove();` to remove `<option value="0"></option>` from active list. You can try putting select box without option tag but not sure it will work or not.

Comment: OR You can try putting select box empty ie without option tag like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/GDKv3/9/)